# Write to HTML5 FileSystem API storage on page unload

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

So I am using the HTML5 FileSystem API to write a large amount of data to a file -- I want to write this data when the HTML page is unloaded, i.e. when the user navigates away.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

It's not working and I am worried that there might be no way to make it work.  Even if you already have a reference to a filesystem, there are at least two callbacks you have to wait for: one after you call getFile which hands you a fileEntry, the next after you call createWriter, which hands you a fileWriter -- not to mention the success/failure callbacks.  I think that the callbacks aren't being called because the user is navigating away.

Is there any way around this?  I tried using onbeforeunload with/ the confirm message for navigating away, just to see if the delay introduced by the dialog would give it time to write, but this doesn't work (maybe due to Javascript being single threaded?)  Now I am wondering if I could keep an open fileWriter the whole time they are on the page, in expectation of when they navigate away?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: does your file system javascript code work in other event like onload..?, may be some thing wrong with your file system handling code can you show that code.?

Answer (score 1):

In some browsers, there's a limit to what you can do (or the amount of work you can do) in `onunload`/`onbeforeunload`. For example, there's a 1-second timeout for `onunload` to complete in Chrome. Any asynchronous tasks you queue up in `onunload` aren't guaranteed to get run once it exits.

(When a page is unloaded the browser deallocates the script execution context, therefore some of the chained callbacks that were not posted before the page is gone would not run.)

I suggest trying to cache the fileEntry/fileWriter like you're doing, but nothing is guaranteed, especially if you're writing a large amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by

1. opening the file and getting a writer on page load (so, I do it all: request quota, get the filesystem, the fileentry, and the filewriter, and then hold on to the filewriter while the user is on the page
2. writing to the file in the "onbeforeunload" event
3. returning a string from "onbeforeunload" so there is a confirm message when you navigate away from the page.  It's annoying but the confirm message is necessary to give the it time to finish writing the file.  If you don't do it, the write never happens.

Still open for better solutions, would be nice to not have the confirm message.